# Pulling a subset of a matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I want to cluster an array, this array contain some angle I want to calculate the difference between of these degree and select one group between this array, this group should have maximum number and the difference between the member of that should not be larger than specific  number.

for example if specific number is **30**
and array is

```
[10 20 30 40 100 120 140]
```

answer should be

```
[10 20 30 40]
```

100-**30** >= **30** so it is not included.

Answer (score 5):

A one-line solution:

```
a = [10 20 30 40 100 120 140];
s = 30;

b = a( abs(a-s) < s )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [10 20 30 40 100 120 140]; #initial array
b = []; #result array
s = 30;
for i = 1:length(a)
    if abs(a(i) - s) < s
        b = [b a(i)];
    end
end
```

Comment: @Amro: Can't upvote this enough -- this is definitely the canonical Matlabesque way of doing it. Can you provide this as a separate answer?