# MATLAB: how do I return entries in a vector?

Tags: matlab

Let's say a=[5;4;3;2;1] and I want all entries > 3, so I want it to spit out v=[5,4].

I know "find" only finds the indices, so it doesn't exactly work.

any suggestions?

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3106646

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Include the inequality test in the index:

```
v = a(a>3)
```